# Missing answer, no response

Tags: discussion, answers, deletion

Today, I'd asked a question regarding the intersections of confocal Parabolas under certain conditions. There was an answer, which apparently partially answered the problem, seems to be missing. Also, is it possible to repost the question, somehow, for more discussion on the same?

Comment: Do you mean an answer or a comment?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was an answer.

Comment: It shows that the answer-er self-deleted the answer. I suggest you to wait for a longer period. After all, it is not suggested to re-post the same question.

Comment: Ohh, alright! Thanks for looking into it.